# i want to change date format to text and export to excel

Tags: php, laravel-5, date-formatting, php-carbon

please i need seome help!

Mycode:

```
$start = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-02-2019')->firstOfMonth();
$end = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-02-2019')->lastOfMonth();
```

i want change date format *01-02-2019* to *Day1* and etc export to excel. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So you just want to append the day number to `Day`? The format specifier for the day number is `j`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = Carbon\Carbon::parse('01-02-2019')->startOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y' );
$end = Carbon\Carbon::parse('01-02-2019')->endOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y' );
```

Try this code.

Comment: https://oursbrand.com/answer/PHP/carbon-date-format-properly-not-formatting-in-laravel

You can also check the answer  against this function 'createFromFormat' i think it will helpful for you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @sheraz ahmad i want change date format from 01-02-2019 to text 'Day1'

Comment: you can also use date('d') function and  attached the day name with string